# Increasing SQL result column limit on IBM Data Studio

Tags: ibm-data-studio

I'm using IBM Data Studio
when I browse down to the columns in a table using the data source explorer it is limiting the number of columns it shows. I don't think it is not a permissions problem as the same credentials work in a different program.

Anyone know is there a setting somewhere to change this?

Answer (score 3):

In the menu bar,

Go to window -> preferences -> Data -> Output

Uncheck "Limit number of rows retrieved"

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody runs into this post, in version 4.1.3, it's menu option Windows -> Preferences -> Data Management -> SQL Development -> SQL Results View Options. Then set 'Max row count' and
'Max display count'. It makes sense for 'Max display count' to be less than or equal to 'Max row count' for the purpose of displaying rows.

Comment: On 4.1.2 it's Windows -> Preferences -> Data Management -> SQL Development -> SQL Results View Options.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the screen you'll find a section informing you with `fetched 500 records, 500 records shown`.

Right click on this line to bring up a screen that lets you change this option.

Validated for version 4.1.2